Issue with road network: shortest path works in QGIS but st_network_cost does not in R
After editing a road network in QGIS to add missing roads and snapping them to existing paths, R doesn’t recognize these additions for routing. In QGIS, my edits route correctly with the Shortest Path tool, but saving as an ESRI shapefile or GPKG and importing into R doesn’t retain the connectivity.
I have a road network (https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/64058) as a shapefile. I want to use it for a TSP routing problem. However, it is missing some roads that I need to access some points of interest, so I added more roads following this method:

import road shapefile into QGIS
in road layer, I added new roads with the Add Line Feature tool
I used Snap Geometries to Layer with tolerance of 50 m, prefer closest point, insert extra vertices where required
Fix Geometries
Remove Null Geometries
Split with Lines

The resulting layer looks how I would expect. When I use Shortest Path (point to point) it is able to route to my points of interest along the new roads:
clip of shortest route to problem point along new roads
However, when I save it as a ESRI shapefile or a GPKG then import into R, it still doesn't route correctly through the new roads using st_network_cost or st_network_paths:
route made in R not going to target point
I have made a reproducible example of my R issue here: https://github.com/eilishmcmaster/netowork_problem
What is the cause for this problem in R and how do I get it to incorporate the new roads?
I have tried connecting nearby unconnected nodes in R (make new edges between unconnected nodes <10 m apart) but this didn't help.
Any help would be much appreciated, I am still new to using geospatial data.

Hi @EMCM, and thanks for your question. I'm one of the sfnetworks developers. Could you please create a new issue in the GitHub repository of sfnetworks (https://github.com/luukvdmeer/sfnetworks/issues) so we do not forget about this problem? Moreover, please notice that we just released v1.0 (https://github.com/luukvdmeer/sfnetworks/discussions/281). Please check whether that already fixes your problem.
